# A good resource for develop an online store with Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I have to develop an online store that sell the access to some rest api. I'm not a Drupal developer, where I can find good resource or open source project to study?

Comment: not sure what you means but look http://drupal.org/node/440086 and a module http://drupal.org/project/ecommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubercart is best module to develop online store with drupal.

Please find the helpfull links for integration and development.

1. http://www.ubercart.org/docs
2. http://www.freelancedrupaldeveloper.ca/ubercart-tutorial-part-1

Also you can use [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce).
Link :- http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/drupal-commerce-setting-shop-drupal-7

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Übercart, open source Drupal based e-commerce project, helps you to develop online store, also supports D7. http://ubercart.org